# Python - print pretty XML create opening and closing tags for empty tags text

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm writing a python application that creates an ElementTree (XML) and then writing it to a file, using minidom's toprettyxml();

```
final_tree = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
fdout.write(final_tree.toprettyxml(indent = '    ')
```

The problem is, that tags which i'm not appending any text comes out with only one tag, for example:

```
<sometag/>
```

I want it to be:

```
<sometag>
</sometag>
```

I want to do it without parsing the whole string (without regex).
Is anybody familiar with such way?
Thanks.

Comment: why should this be a problem?

Comment: Because it should look like the second way.

Comment: The second one has a newline between the tags. It's not same as empty.

Comment: Yes, but why? No xml parser should have problems with the first form. On the other hand, the second is _not_ completely equivalent to the firs, as it contains whitespace. If anything then the equivalent to `<sometag/>` is `<sometag></sometag>` (without any whitespace between).

Comment: I understand that, it's a requirement.

Comment: replace those tags with <tag>&nbsp;</tag> or alike. This will prevent them from being made emtpy in the output.

Comment: Pretty printing typically introduces whitespace anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is hard-wired in `minidom.py` (have a look at `writexml()` method in `class Element`).  It is not meant to be changed, but for the *current implementation* you can monkey-patch it like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

t = minidom.parseString('<a><b></b></a>')

def patcher(method):
  def patching(self, *args, **kwargs):
    old = self.childNodes
    try:
      if not self.childNodes:
        class Dummy(list):
          def __nonzero__(self):  # Python2
            return True
          def __bool__(self):  # Python3
            return True
        old, self.childNodes = self.childNodes, Dummy([])
      return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    finally:
      self.childNodes = old
  return patching

t.firstChild.__class__.writexml = patcher(t.firstChild.__class__.writexml)

print t.toprettyxml()
```

But of course I cannot recommend such a hack.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i ended up using regex.

Comment: Thanks @Alfe. I made use of your hack while taking the nand2tetris course, where you have to match an XML answer key exactly. I guess I could have pretty printed that XML, but I liked leaving the answer key alone.