# How to write empty xml element with open and close tags in multiline file in python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I use lxml to write xml files.
I want two things, I can do each of them on its own, but can't do both of them:

1. empty tags to be: `<tag></tag>` rather than `<tag />` (method="html")
2. xml file will contain new lines between elements. (pretty_print=True)

How can I do it? If the solution is to use other xml library it is also fine for me.

EDIT: Here is a code example:

```python
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Element("root")
    empty_element = Element("empty")
    root.append(empty_element)
    class_tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
    class_tree.write("output1.xml", pretty_print=True)  # work
    class_tree.write("output2.xml", method="html")  # work
    class_tree.write("output3.xml", pretty_print=True, method="html")  # don't work together
```

Comment: this question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813938/python-print-pretty-xml-create-opening-and-closing-tags-for-empty-tags-text)

Comment: Well, you can fix it by not using `method="html"`. Instead, add `empty_element.text = ''`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548368/407651

Comment: thanks @mzjn, it works in the example but it does not work in the general case where there are more than two elements. (you can add second empty element as a son of the first empty and test it)

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. But the code in the question does not demonstrate the "general case".

Comment: @mzjn Your'e right, I wanted to provide minimal example (I didn't know that specifically in this case your solution will work) and I think my last comment clarrifies the issue.

Comment: Yes, but all relevant info should be in the question itself. It should not be necessary to read the comments to understand what the real issue is.

Comment: I get you and appreciate your intentions, but I think my question is clear enough and I prefer discussing solutions to my question and not ways to make the question perfect.

Comment: Can you share an example of the desired output?