# Full tag in to_xml pandas in any case

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code like this:

```py
    data_to_string = data_from_table.to_xml(path_or_buffer= file_name + ".xml", index=False,
                                            root_name="convoy", row_name="vehicle", xml_declaration=False)
```

It works fine with files containing several rows but if there is nothing to export, i have only

```
<convoy/>
```

in my .xml.

How can I fix the code to have:

```
<convoy>
</convoy>
```

in any cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is [hard-coded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815840/9152905) into the xml-library.

Your requirement can be fulfilled by checking whether there are rows in your dataframe and, if not, by creating an empty `html`-string ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548368/9152905) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972801/9152905)) instead and writing that to the output.

Be aware that `<convoy/>` and `<convoy></convoy>` are [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2771410/9152905) in **xml**.

Here is a fully working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

file_name = "test"
path = file_name + ".xml"
root_name = "convoy"
row_name = "vehicle"

data_from_table = pd.DataFrame()
if len(data_from_table.index) > 0:
    data_to_string = data_from_table.to_xml(
        path_or_buffer=path,
        index=False,
        root_name=root_name,
        row_name=row_name,
        xml_declaration=False,
    )
else:
    elem = etree.Element(root_name)
    empty_xml = etree.tostring(elem, method="html", encoding="unicode")
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(empty_xml)
```

Comment: equivalent in xml - i know that. But for ex in my education I should make like I wrote.

Comment: it worked for me. thanx! I was starting to create a bycle with squre wheels: to open xml, to read, to find, to replace to write and close. your decision is much easier :)